# Ayuda con la incorporación de font-awesome

Tags: css, sass, font-awesome, less

Estoy realizando una practica con archivos .less.
y mi problema es que cuando "agrego" font-awesome a mi proyecto. y al cargar el *index*, me muestra un cuadro solamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi archivo framework.less:

```
    @path-bootstrap: '../../node_modules/bootstrap/less/';
    @path-jasny:     '../../node_modules/jasny-bootstrap/less/';
    @path-forta:     '../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/less/';
    @fa-font-path:   '../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';

@import 'var-bootstrap.less';
@import 'var-jasny.less';

// Mixins
@import '@{path-bootstrap}mixins.less';

// Reset
@import '@{path-bootstrap}normalize.less';
@import '@{path-bootstrap}print.less';

// Core CSS
@import '@{path-bootstrap}scaffolding.less';
@import '@{path-bootstrap}type.less';
@import '@{path-bootstrap}grid.less';
@import '@{path-bootstrap}forms.less';
@import '@{path-bootstrap}buttons.less';

// Icons
@import '@{path-forta}fontawesome.less'; // font awesome

// Components
@import '@{path-bootstrap}navs.less';
@import '@{path-bootstrap}navbar.less';
@import '@{path-bootstrap}jumbotron.less';

// Offcanvas
@import "@{path-jasny}navmenu.less";
@import "@{path-jasny}offcanvas.less";

// Utility classes
@import '@{path-bootstrap}utilities.less';
@import '@{path-bootstrap}responsive-utilities.less';
```

Este es una imagen del directorio que manejo.
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi lo llamo en mi index.html

```
<i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
```

Cabe mencionar que estoy utilizando KOALA como preeprosesador.
no me arroja ningun error. koala me genera estos archivos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así los llamo en mi *index*:

```
 <link href="assets/css/frameworks.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

Agrega el siguiente cdn a tu index:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Y recuerdas que tu versión de Bootstrap tiene que ser la 4. Aquí tienes una galería completa de emoticones `https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery`.

Avísame si te sirvió mi respuesta.

Comment: no quisiera tener que "linquear" los archivos de esa manera, amigo